# What is the most scalable way to convert json data from one form to another in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Here's an example:

Original json:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "item1",
    "description": "test1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "item2",
    "description": "test2"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "item3",
    "description": "test3"
  }
]
```

After conversion:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "order": "item1",
    "task": "test1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "order": "item2",
    "task": "test2"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "order": "item3",
    "task": "test3"
  }
]
```

So far  I've been doing it like so, but it's not that easily scalable when new forms of data gets added:

```js
newjson = [];

oldjson.forEach(elem => {
  newjson.push({
    id: elem.id,
    order: elem.name,
    task: elem.description
  });
});
```

What I'm looking for is having one function that would be able to convert data from one form to another both ways using some value pair list similar to this:

```
propertyMapping = [
  ["id","id"],
  ["name","order"],
  ["description","task"]
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) from the passed array of properties and return an [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) after mapping the [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) against the `Map`. Here accepting either an array or individual object and remapping accordingly.

```js
function remapProperties(objectOrArray, propertyMapping) {
  const propertyMap = new Map(propertyMapping);
  const remap = o => Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => [propertyMap.get(k) ?? k, v]));

  return Array.isArray(objectOrArray)
    ? objectOrArray.map(remap)
    : remap(objectOrArray);
}

const input = [{ "id": 1, "name": "item1", "description": "test1" }, { "id": 2, "name": "item2", "description": "test2" }, { "id": 3, "name": "item3", "description": "test3" }];
const propertyMapping = [["id", "id"], ["name", "order"], ["description", "task"]];

console.log(remapProperties(input, propertyMapping));

// also accepts individual objects
console.log(remapProperties({
  "id": 1,
  "name": "item1",
  "description": "test1"
}, propertyMapping));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can loop on property mapping and if data properties match to one property mapping change porty in a loop like array.map

```js
const data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "item1",
    "description": "test1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "item2",
    "description": "test2"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "item3",
    "description": "test3"
  }
]

const propertyMapping = [
  ["id", "id"],
  ["name", "order"],
  ["description", "task"]
];

let result = data.map(elem => {
  let final = {};
  propertyMapping.forEach(property => {
    if (elem[property[0]]) {
      final[property[1]] = elem[property[0]];
    }
  });
  return final;
});

console.log(result);
```